# Postgres-Queries in Rails: where not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, where-clause

I use Rails with PostgreSQL and it works perfectly for queries like this:

```
# Does hstore_column contain key?

scoped_users = User.where('hstore_column ? :key', key: 'name_of_key')
```

Now my problem: How can I invert this query / how can I find all users which **do not** have a specific key specified?

```
# I tried this query amongst others, but it does not work:

scoped_users = User.where('hstore_column ? :key = FALSE', key: 'name_of_key')
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
where('NOT ( hstore_column ? :key )', key: 'name_of_key')
```